# Selenium - disable test and do not show in test explorer

Tags: c#, selenium

Is there a way to decorate a Selenium test in C# so that the test will not appear, and will not be executed in Test Explorer?  Without commenting the entire test case

Comment: What testing framework are you using? XUnit, MSTest, NUnit?

Comment: Selenium and XUnit

Comment: Yes, it's `[Ignore]` https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons

Comment: [Ignore] still shows the test in test explorer with a triangle exclamation point

Comment: Is that a big deal? The only way to have a test not show in Test Explorer is to make it _not a test_, such as removing _all_ the attributes. Ignore just says "yes it's a test, just don't run it".